# Open Source or Commercial license?

Tags: open-source, licensing

I am starting to get a small (just me at the moment) web design company off the ground and there is one thing that is a bit fuzzy to me - whether I can legally use open source apps in sites that I built without paying.

Say, for example, that I want to incorporate CKEditor into a custom built CMS on site that I produce. Should I be paying a commercial license to do so?

I am a small startup at the moment and really do not have big bucks to go out buying OEM or commercial licenses. Where is the line between "personal" and commercial when it comes to design?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: Holy cow, blast from the past getting attention now ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CKEditor can be used without paying a commercial license.  The commercial license is available if GPL, LGPL, or MPL are not satisfactory.  The text below is stating that, for companies that cannot use software under an Open Source license for whatever reason, they can still purchase a commercial license.

```
For many companies and products, Open Source licenses are not an option.
This is why the CKSource Closed Distribution License (CDL) has been introduced.
```

For your use, I would recommend either LGPL or MPL to be safe.  The GPL requires all software linked to the GPL code to also be GPL (or a compatible license).  This is why it is considered a "viral license" by many companies.  The other licenses do not carry this requirement.  The LGPL specifically removes it; that is why it is known as the "Library" or "Lesser" GPL.

**As far as the line between commercial and non-commercial use, that depends on the software that you are integrating with**.  It is perfectly fine for someone to pay you to create a site - it does not mean that the resulting work itself is commercial.  You are not integrating the editor in your web design services site, so that shouldn't be the criteria you use to decide.  You would be integrating it in the site you have been hired to create.  If this site itself provides or is a front for commercial products or services, then it's commercial.  But again, you do not need to purchase the commercial license if your client is OK with the terms of LGPL or MPL (I don't see why they wouldn't).

Comment: Thank you for being polite and providing to the point information :)

Answer (score 2):

CKEditor (previously FCKEditor) can be licensed under GPL, LGPL, MPL, and even a [CKSource Closed Distribution License (CDL)](http://cksource.com/cdl).  GPL and LGPL (probably MPL as well) are distribution-based licenses.  That is, they only apply when you're re-distributing the software.  Although it's not clear from your question, my guess is you just want to 'use' CKEditor in a website design as opposed to incorporating it into website software that you're going to distribute and/or sell.  In the use-in-website case, the [ASP loophole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP_loophole) probably applies to your scenario regardless of personal or commercial use and there's no need to pay for anything or apply any licenses on your website work.

If, however, you turn around and decide you want to try an distribute and/or sell your custom CMS that incorporates the CKEditor (for example, sell it to other website designers that need a CMS), then you must abide by the rules of whichever license you select and pay accordingly if you decide the CDL license is most appropriate for your needs.  The CKEditor website has good examples of reasons why you would choose the CDL option.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the http://ckeditor.com/license page ? It seems pretty clear it's free for non-commercial use, but you need a license for commercial use.

More generally, it depends on the license of the app in question. Open-source apps are typically free to use, but may place restrictions on redistribution. IF the license is MIT, BSD or Apache you can essentially do what you want providing you keep their copyright notice there. If the license is GPL, the requirement to redistribute your code under a copyleft license too is typically incompatible with commercial use.

Comment: I was merely using that as an example. The question was when would it become commercial use..

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check the license of whatever you're using, but in general you can use open source stuff for anything as long as you don't claim it as your own.

Comment: So you're saying as long as I do not claim to have programmed the app (as in the example given, CKEditor) myself? It's not as though I am making a standalone product that will be mass distributed, this is on a case by case basis with each site.. that's where I get a little fuzzy. From the perspective of the website's owner, my client, it is in a way personal use - on their site. But commercial in that they paid me to produce the site that utilizes that app

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not as simple as just the two licensing models, since open source licenses fall under several other categories.  In some cases, you cannot release your code under a different license with an open source library linked to it (like the GPL).  In other cases, you can make changes to the open source code and re-release it as closed source (like the Apache License).  See [this reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_software_licenses) for free software licenses and which are okay to link or release with different licenses.